# как установить эмулятор терминала по-умолчанию?

Tags: linux, gui

У меня в системе черненький, а IDE при отладке почему-то запускает другой, белый.

Какими командами сконфигурировать, чтобы использовался один и тот же везде?

конкретные названия я специально не пишу, меня интересует решение в общем случае.

Comment: в настройках IDE поменять xterm на Ваш черненький. Конкретнее ничего не пишу, это решение в общем случае.

Comment: да-да, а ещё можно в системе настроить беленький для всех, а автору IDE написать багу, что не использует системные настройки

Comment: @hse5yzdx - у всех врятли, разные рабочие столы поразному хранят терминал по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Терминал по умолчанию задаётся в переменной окружения TERM.

```
$ env |grep term
TERM=xterm-256color
```

Чаще всего случается наоборот. DE(окружение рабочего стола) использует терминал **предлагает** в своей менюшке использовать терминал который с ней поставляется. При этом этот "черненький" терминал нигде не прописан по умолчанию кроме как в настройках DE(и то не всегда явно).

Например, Gnome хранит предпочитаемый терминал в схеме dconf `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal`. Чтоб реализовать нужную вам возможность требуется писать поддержку dconf в Вашей любимой среде разработки, на что разработчики не пойдут всвязи с возросшим числом связанных библиотек и ухудшением совместимости с другими DE.

Самми же IDE хотели бы использовать терминал по умолчанию, но практически всегда в этой переменной стоит `xterm` или `xterm-256color` поэтому этот параметр вынесен в настройках (в IDE с зелено-желтым значечком точно).

По-настоящему следит за переменной программа `wine` запуская в указанном эмуляторе консольные приложения. Сходу больше примеров правильного использования этого механизма не вспомню.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives  x-terminal-emulator (эмулятор терминала для X-server)

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение, +1 способ указать терминал по умолчанию и его также воспримут не все. Когда сидел на Убунте(там на альтернативах тоже сделанно многое) частенько запускался "не тот" терминал. Примером тот же wine и kde-шные програмки...